# How to list all Unicode strings starting and ending with a particular character?

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I am trying to list all the words have particular ending and  starting.
This is  `ണ്`  my ending character and `വി` is my starting character.

this is my input

```
പാമോലിന്‍ കേസിന്റെ വിചാരണ നടപടികള്‍ ഹൈക്കോടതി രണ്ടുമാസത്തേക്ക് സ്‌റ്റേചെയ്തു. കേസ് പിന്‍വലിക്കണമെന്ന ആവശ്യം നിരസിച്ച തൃശ്ശൂര്‍ വിജിലന്‍സ് കോടതി ഉത്തരവിനെതിരെ വിജിലന്‍സ് സമര്‍പ്പിച്ച ഹര്‍ജിയിലാണ് ഇടക്കാല ഉത്തരവ്.
```

The expected output is

```
വിചാരണ
```

How can I write regular expression for it ?

```
re.findall(ur'\bവി\w+ണ\b', inputtext, flags=re.UNICODE) won´t work
```

I still don´t understand why its  not working like English, Please add this fact to the answer so that I could get better understanding of the problem

Comment: And what kind of input will you give the expression? What kind of output do you expect?

Comment: There is *no* word in that text that matches your criteria. `വിചാരണ` is *not* a match for a word ending in `ണ്`. If in Malayalam Sangam it is supposed to be the same, you need to tell us how that works in Unicode.

Comment: if you change  the expression to re.findall(ur'\bവി\w+ണ\b', inputtext, flags=re.UNICODE) then also it will not work ? Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input text is full of a mix of word and non-word characters, so the only way to determine a word boundary is to look behind and ahead for spaces:

```
re.findall(ur'(?<![^ ])വി[^ ]+ണ്?(?![^ ])', inputtext, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

where `inputtext` is a Unicode value. The `(?<!...)` and `(?!...)` are negative lookbehind and lookahead assertions; the match locations in the text that are *not* preceded or followed by a non-space character, respectively.

Within your boundary text, we match non-spaces as well.

This matches your expected input:

```
>>> print re.findall(ur'(?<![^ ])വി[^ ]+ണ്?(?![^ ])', inputtext, flags=re.UNICODE)[0]
വിചാരണ
```

Comment: @karu: Why would that not work? The regular expression still matches both characters.

Comment: @martjn  I have tested it now

Comment: @karu: There are **no** words in your input that begin with `വി` and end with `ണ്`, actually. There is one that ends with `രണ` but that's not the same.

Comment: if you change the Unicode ണ് to ണ in expression then also it will no work

Comment: Are any of the codepoints in between perhaps not word characters? It is really hard to tell for someone unfamiliar with the script to tell if they are.

Comment: @karu: ah, a lot of the codepoints in your input text are not word characters for `\w+`, so we need to redefine what makes a word boundary here.

Comment: Ok, I still don´t understand why its not working like English, Please add this fact to the answer so that I could get better understanding of the problem

Answer (score 0):

... or, if you want something more verbal

```
original_list = ('abc', 'ccbd', 'abbc')
filtered = tuple(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('a') and x.endswith('c'), original_list))
filtered
('abc', 'abbc')
```

but it definately doesn't answer your question.